# Is there any established order for 'ls' arguments?

Tags: bash, shell, posix, zsh, ls

I'm a student and as part of my cursus I must recode the `ls`command and reproduce its behaviour the best possible.

On Mac (El Capitan 10.11.6), using the terminal iTerm 2(zsh), I get:

```
user> ls . -R
ls: -R: No such file or directory
```

And on Arch (latest version), using the default text interface(bash) I get:

```
user> ls . -R
<current directory content>
```

Although I'd rather trust Arch, is it correct for ls to refuse its option after a directory has been specified ? And is there any documentation declaring the arguments order ?

Comment: BTW, `ls` isn't part of either bash or zsh but an external command provided by the OS vendor; it'll behave identically on a given OS (unless an alternate version is installed, as by Macports or Homebrew, absent functions, aliases, or other configuration that explicitly alters behavior) whichever shell is in use.

Comment: I wasn't sure, that's why I included it ^^ thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [POSIX utility syntax guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html), entry #9:

> Guideline 9:
>
> All options should precede operands on the command line.

Thus, the usage that POSIX guarantees will be supported is `ls -R .`, as `-R` is an option, and `.` is an operand.

GNU tools don't generally enforce this guideline (which is why Arch lets you put your arguments in the opposite order) -- but for maximum portability it's wise to write your software assuming it to be enforced.

If you want to be **certain** that `-R` will be treated as an operand rather than an argument, whatever your platform, you can use `--` to separate the two categories: `ls -l -- -R` will treat `-l` as an option and `-R` as an operand, and thus will look for a file or directory named `-R` and provide a long-format listing; this is defined by POSIX utility syntax guideline #10.